# Register gcm for chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a chrome Apps use push notification of GCM. I have a problem, when i don't login account on chrome. I can't receive registerId from GCM. I think a idea. When registerId empty, i show notification, request user login to chrome and show login page account on chrome. But because of security concerns , the chrome does not allow access to its setting from external links . How is open "chrome://settings/" from external links? Can register to gcm, If i don't want login account on chrome?

**My code:**

```
function setValue()
{
//var thongtin=$('#status').val();
 //var thongtin = document.getElementById('status').innerText;
if(registrationId == "")
{
    // Pop up a notification to show notification.
    chrome.notifications.create(getNotificationId(), {
    title: 'CLOUD MONITOR',
    iconUrl: 'gcm_128.png',
    type: 'basic',
    message: 'You must sign in account gmail on google chrome!'
    }, function() {});

    //event click to notification
    chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function() {     
        window.location.href = "chrome://settings/"
    });
}
else
{
//http://mtraffic.longvan.net/device_register?regId=" +registrationId+"&device=android
//document.getElementById('webviewSendData').src = "http://192.168.64.246:8080/register?REGID=" +registrationId+"&DEVICE=desktop";
document.getElementById('webviewSendData').src = "http://mtraffic.longvan.net/device_register?regId="+registrationId+"&device=android";
//document.getElementById('webviewSendData').src = "http://192.168.64.124:8080/monitor/device_register?regId=" +registrationId+"&device=android";
//var url = "http://192.168.64.124:8080/monitor/device_register?regId=" +registrationId+"&device=android";
//httpGet(url);
//alert(thongtin);
//document.getElementById('status').innerHTML="Infomation New";
// Pop up a notification to show notification.

}
}
```

**This code don't run.**

> ```
> chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function() {   
>         window.location.href = "chrome://settings/"
>     });
> ```

**I fix code as  Derek 朕會功夫.**

> chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function() {
>               chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://settings/"});
>           });

*And receive error notify: Error in event handler for notifications.onClicked:TypeError: Can't read property 'create' of underfined.*

Comment: `chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://settings/"})`

Comment: see here:https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Not in an App.

Comment: @Xan - You sure? Because I saw `tabs` is on the list in https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permissions and I thought it's available to apps. Nonetheless, can `chrome.app.window.create` do the same thing?

Comment: @Derek You should be looking at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index Also, no, `app.window` can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid at the moment it's not possible.

Chrome Apps don't have access to `tabs`/`windows` API that can open privileged pages; that's why Derek's suggestion does not work.

**In future**, they may be a way to do this with `chrome.browser` API. See [this feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=358315), [this proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hwzjc2SC9Mb6Usu02N1AIB2ml_fNokvOPetEpD_q56A/edit), and please leave feedback there with your use case.