# Access local chrome-urls in chrome-app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

How can I get access to the local chrome-urls to receive content from there? For example use an iframe for chrome://version or access the content directly with AJAX.

Any ideas? I tried the following permission:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "permissions": [
      "chrome://*",
      "chrome://version"
    ]
  }
}
```

--> **"Not allowed to load local resource"**

I had a look at the possible permissions but didn't find anything that fits my expectation. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you [can't access `chrome://` URLs in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637721/934239).

It's indirectly possible in an extension through `tabs` API, but there's nothing for the moment that can allow an app to do that.